# Action argument supporting multiple units as string

Tags: c#, api, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

I've got a controller with two actions that need to support two units: `hours` & `times`. The url should read like this:

> ```
> api/workflows/active/next/hour
> api/workflows/active/next/time
> api/workflows/active/next/3/hours
> api/workflows/active/next/3/times
> ```

In order to not write any extra validation for the `unit` parameter I have defined the last route segment as `regex`:

```cs
[HttpGet("active/next/{unit:regex(^(hour|time))}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNextSingle(string unit)
{
    return await GetNextMany(1, $"{unit}s");
}

[HttpGet("active/next/{value:int:min(1):max(10)}/{unit:regex(^(hours|times))}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetNextMany(int value, string unit)
{
    return Ok(new { value, unit });              
}
```

Would say this is how it's usually done or are there other smarter ways?

Comment: For me these feel like more a filter then a routing parameter. So I would rather go with query parameters instead, for examle `api/workflows/active/next?unit=time` or `api/workflows/active/next?unit=hour&value=3`

Comment: @PeterCsala my reasoning behind not using query paramets here was that there is no `api/workflows/active/next` as it would confuse the user about any implicit defaults if it had any so a route seemed to be more natural. It also reads nicely ;-]

Comment: If you just want to have a web API then any convention is acceptable. If you want to have a REST API then your uri should refer/point to a resource. IMHO neither `/times` nor `/3/hours` are resources.

Comment: you could do `api/workflows/active/next/3/hours/1` you could do the same for the times as well. make an action for each, and  just mark `GetNextMany` as `private` and recall it from both actions. would better in maintainability and readability.

Comment: @iSR5 what would the `1` at the and of `next/3/hours/1` stand for?

Comment: @t3chb0t oh, my bad, that routing got me confused a bit. I thought (next) is a filter along with `hour`. so next 3 items within an hour period. mixing routing and filtering all together like that has its disadvantages. I would go with `QueryString` or just do `POST` with a body if you need more control with less routing parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Action argument supporting multiple units

There is "hour" and "everythingElse". "times" is not a unit really, merely counting. For that matter "hour" fits in that category too.  The differentiation of hour|times seems incongruent.

The conceptual inconsistency has led to a lack of extensibility; fine if there are no multiple units; then I'm agreeing with [@PeterCsala it's filtering, not routing comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286396/action-argument-supporting-multiple-units-as-string#comment570157_286396)

---

Comment: I guess calling it a _unit_ wasn't the best idea as now everyone is picking up on that :P There is no _everythingElse_ resource. The url `api/workflows/active/next` does not exist and doesn't make sense on its own because it doesn't specify "next what?". Only the other segments give it a concrete meaning. Query parameters should filter a resource and you cannot filter something that doesn't actually exist so using query parameters would be confusing as without them you'd get a 404.

Comment: I wanted to see how Microsoft defines their Graph APIs, but when I see this `GET /me/onenote/notebooks/getRecentNotebooks(includePersonalNotebooks=includePersonalNotebooks-value)` with `getRecentNotbooks` instead of `notebooks/recent` I don't think we should use it as inspiration ;-]